# How come calling main() displays a NameError?

Tags: python, nameerror

I'm very new to Python and programming in general, so please bear with me while reading this. I'm using Python 3.6.1. Here is my code:

```
import random
greetings = ["how are you", "hello", "hey", "hi", "whats up"]
special_characters = [".", "?", "!"]
def main():
    i = input()
    if i in greetings or greetings and special_characters:
        print(random.choice(greetings) + random.choice(special_characters))
        main()
    else:
        print("Sorry, I don't understand what you just said.")
        main()
main()
```

The problem is, when I try saying something like "hey!" or "hi," it comes up with this error message:

```
NameError: name 'main' is not defined
```

I've tried multiple times to fix this, but I simply couldn't figure out the solution.

Comment: It seems that your  `main` has infinite recursion.

Comment: I can't reproduce any `NameError`.  *Copy and paste* your *actual* code.  Do not retype it, do not paraphrase it.  In order words: post a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2):

In `special_characters`, you have a `'` where it should be `"`.

Comment: Oh, sorry. That was just a typo that wasn’t in the actual code.

Comment: @thatonehayk that suggests that something else is wrong in your code. Do you run that entire code block as a script? Is there any other code you have not provided?

Comment: Yes, I ran it as a script. Also, that is the entirety of the code.

Comment: Even the default syntax coloring catches that one.

Comment: Surprisingly, that isn’t the problem. I tried saying something else like “lol that didnt work stupid” but it still didn’t work.

Comment: Is that the full text of the error? It should also say which line the error was encountered.

Comment: I copied and pasted the code above and it ran fine. Try changing the name of the function?

Comment: Hell, I don’t know what it did but by changing the name of the function the code actually worked. Thanks for the help.